# Remove username from terminal title

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to be able to retitle my terminal windows.  I've found many examples on the web, but no matter what I do, the string is always prefixed by my username.  I want to remove that; how do I do so?

I'm using Yosemite.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your username is coming up in the Terminal title, because when you launch Terminal it is starting off in your home directory as the current "working directory."

There are two ways to do this:

### 1)  Yosemite and earlier

a)  You can create an AppleScript that launches Terminal and sets it Window title

```
tell application "Terminal"
   activate
   set custom title to "This is my Custom Title"
end tell
```

b)  You can set it using bash's PROMPT_COMMAND variable in `.bashrc`.  For instance, you can add the line `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;This is my custom title for ${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'`

Every time you open terminal, it will set that as your window title (assuming you are running bash, of course)

There's more info on using this method from this post:  https://superuser.com/questions/79972/set-the-title-of-the-terminal-window-to-the-current-directory

### 2) In El Capitan forward:

You can turn it off by deslecting the "Display Working Directory" option in Terminal preferences.

[image]

The change is immediate, you don't need to relaunch Terminal; your username will no longer show on the title of the window

Comment: On my machine, there's no such option AFAICT.  Here's the list I see under Preferences ==> Window:  Active process name; Shell command name; Profile name; TTY name; Dimensions; Command key.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I revised my answer - I don't have the MBA with Yosemite that I used to source the answer  as I just gave it back to the owner.  All I have is El Capitan now, so I revised it accordingly and tried to provide "universal" instructions.